# During routine use system freezes. Upon reboot, "error:no such device; error: unknown device"

Tags: boot, grubrescue, error-handling

Since 2017, I've had my laptop setup to dual boot windows 7 (from the internal drive) and Ubuntu (the default; from an external drive), in those 4 years it's been fine and there's been no change to the hardware or install.  Out of the blue, yesterday, after being idle for a couple hours, I noticed that the screen was frozen. I rebooted and the following is displayed:

> error: no such device 6c1b9...
> error: unknown filesystem.
> Entering rescue mode...
> Grub rescue>

I get the error even if the external drive isn't plugged in. And swapping out its data cable didn't seem to make difference

I saw other questions related to this issue, but they all seemed to be triggered by system modifications-not routine/idle activity.

Is there a way to resolve this without losing the data on the drive?

Edit: I tried the boot-repair tool and it sent me further down the rabbit hole.  The system now boots directly to windows (internal drive), but the external drive isn't recognized at all and there's no evidence of a multiboot at all during start up.

Comment: Then drive likely failed so the chances of data recovery are very slim.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: @David I'm not sure. Up until the crash I was keeping it fairly up-to-date, so presumably the most recent version.